# Vim: indenting a level deeper when enter is pressed (and some conditions are met)

Tags: vim, indentation

I'm writing a plugin for the dg language, what can I do to auto-indent when a line terminates with some specified symbols?

For example, if the line terminates with `->` or `~>` or `=>` and I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then the cursor would go on a new line indented a level deeper. I guess I should put the code in the `indent` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in indent methods (`cindent`, `autoindent`, `smartindent`) won't suffice for a custom language. You need to write your own *indent plugin*, which would go into `~/.vim/indent/dg.vim`.

Basically, you need to write a Vimscript function that examines the current (and previous) line(s) and determines the indent level from this. This function is then installed into `'indentexpr'`. See `:help indent-expression`, which unfortunately only recommends to have a look at the existing indent scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to take inspiration from the `vim-coffee` plugin.